# How to store equivalences in connected components labeling algorithm i Fortran

Tags: algorithm, fortran, fortran90

I have to implement connected components labeling algorithm Fortran. I have a clear idea on how to scan thee matrix, but what about storing and recover equivalence classes? I guess that in many other programming languages is an easy task, but i have to do it in Fortran. How can i do it?

**First Edit:** Following the pseudo code on wikipedia about [connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling), what i have no idea on how to do in Fortran is

`linked[label] = union(linked[label], L)`

Comment: Fortran has its strengths and weakness (as do all programming languages) but I see no reason why what is an easy task in many other programming languages should be a difficult task in Fortran.  Perhaps if you posted either some pseudo-code or even (shock, horror !) the Fortran code you are developing, we could help.

Comment: That is a *very* broad question. Could you be a little more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: Crikey, the Wikipedia article on connected component labelling even provides a pseudo-code that I could translate, almost line for line, directly into Fortran.  What is the problem ?

Comment: Yes i know that is broad question, but i only need to know the way on how to store the equivalence classes. Still there is not any code, because i don't know how to do the main task but, i can expose my problem with much details.

Comment: @High Performance Mark Yes i have see that pseudo code. The problem is that i don't know how to translate the part referred to equivalence classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some fragments of an answer.  It looks like you need to implement a data structure which represents a set of labels.  The first decision you have to make is to decide how to model a label.  I see 3 obvious approaches:

1. Use integers.
2. Use character variables of length 1 (or 2 or whatever you want).
3. Define a type with whatever components you want it to have.

The second decision is how to implement a set of labels.  I see 3 obvious approaches:

1. Use an array of labels (array of integers, array of character(len=2), array of type(label), it doesn't matter) whose size is fixed at compile time.  You have to be fairly certain that the size you hard-wire is always going to be large enough.  This is not a very appealing approach; I should probably not have mentioned it.
2. Use an array of labels whose size is set at run-time.  This means using an allocatable array.  You'll have to figure out how to set this to the right size at run-time, if it is possible at all.
3. Implement a type representing a set of labels. This type might, for example model a set as a linked list.  But that is not the only way to model the set, the type might model the set of labels as an array, and do some fancy footwork to re-size the array if required. By defining a type, of course, you give yourself the freedom to change the internal representation of the set without modifying the code which uses the functionality exposed by the set type.

Depending on the choices you have made it should be quite straightforward to implement a union function to add a new label to an existing set of labels.

Note though, that there are many other ways to tackle this problem.  You might, for example, start with a set of already-defined component labels and drop from the set the ones you don't need to use.

Since you seem to be new to Fortran, here's a list of language features you need to be familiar with to implement the foregoing.

1. How much of the Fortran 2003 standard your compiler implements.
2. Defining, and using, derived types.
3. Allocatable arrays, allocating arrays, moving allocations.
4. Arrays of derived types.
5. Type-bound procedures.
6. Pointers, and targets.